# Problema em deixar uma div responsive

Tags: html, css

Bom eu criei uma div com um fundo e um form dentro dela para deixar centralizada + 1 logo.
html:

```
<div class="fundobg">
<img src="images/logosecure.png">
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="text" name="pesquisar" placeholder="PESQUISAR">
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fundobg{
    background-image: url(../images/fundo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex; align-itens: center; justify-contents: center;
}
.fundobg img{width: 100px; height: 100px;}

.fundobg form{}
```

como está no momento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu diminuo o zoom não fica responsive:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu queria deixar o width de 1280 e dentro desse widh o logo e um espaço o buscar, mas não estou conseguindo alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, ao invés de ficar sofrendo, fazendo CSS na mão, usa Semantic UI, tem tudo que você precisa para fazer um site bonito, e não custa nenhum centavo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas usar a palavra "responsivo" não ajuda muito. Frameworks prometem (e entregam) responsividade, mas te darão resultados padronizados. Fazer o CSS manualmente [oferece mais liberdade](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/css-grid-melhor-que-bootstrap/), mas exige mais planejamento: não se trata de dizer "quero responsivo", e sim qual comportamento desejo.

Minha primeira dica seria: use [medidas relativas](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/). Por exemplo, se você deseja que seu logo não diminua com zoom out, aplique uma regra parecida com `{ height: 5vh; }` que fará com que a imagem tenha altura igual a 5% da dimensão vertical da tela. No caso de fontes, estabeleça um tamanho fixo para todo o documento, aplicando uma regra como `html { font-size: 10px; }`, e para os seus elementos utilize a unidade "rem". Por exemplo, se você quer uma fonte em 16px, você aplicaria a regra `{ font-size: 1.6rem; }`. Por que isso? Porque quando você quiser redimensionar as fontes, basta redimencionar a fonte com unidade absoluta e todas as fontes fixadas em rem se adequarão automaticamente. O que me leva para segunda dica...

...use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries). Apenas aplicar porcentagens não te ajudará em telas muito grandes ou pequenas. No seu caso, certamente você desejaria comportamentos diferentes em grandes e pequenas telas. No seu caso, `@media only screen and (min-height: 1000px) { .fundobg>img{ height: 5vh; } }`, por exemplo, asseguraria que somente em telas grandes a imagem teria 5% do tamanho da tela (telas menores poderiam usar um tamanho fixo). Você pode usar media queries para aumentar o tamanho da fonte fixa conforme a tela cresce - e esse valor cascadearia.

Uma terceira dica é usar valores min-height, max-width etc, que podem te economizar media queries. Por exemplo, `.fundobg>img { height: 5vh; min-height: 100px; }` te ajudaria a a crescer a logo quando necessário, sem diminuí-lo demais em pequenas telas.

Quarta dica: coloque seus vários elementos em contêineres, preferencialmente [flex](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox/) e [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout), com unidades em porcentagem, e faça regras mais bem elaboradas (como media query) para os contêineres.

Ainda dando dicas, não estabeleça ambas altura *e* largura de imagens, porque assim você pode acabar deformando a imagem (lembre-se que é melhor usar a imagem do tamanho certo que escalá-la). Também evite colocar várias regras de CSS em uma única linha. Além disso, para obter um CSS [DRY](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), tente usar vários seletores com poucas regras, ao invés de seletores individuais repetindo a regra (assim você poderá alterá-los a todos facilmente). Ou seja, isso...

```
.a, .b{
    regra 1;
}
.a{
    regra2;
}
```

...é preferível a isso...

```
.a{
    regra1;
    regra2;
}
.b{
    regra1;
}
```

... ao menos para os aderentes do DRY.

Uma última observação: se você quer fazer o CSS manualmente, considere usar o preprocessador [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) - ele certamente o tornará mais produtivo.

PS: Preferiria ter feito um comentário, mas a reputação não permite.

Comment: opa mano vou procurar sobre o sass, você aconselha utilizar o bootstrap tb? Eu já arrumei o error era coisa bem simples e outra coisa existe algo que possa me ajudar a criar um carrinho de compras nesse estilo: http://neshastore.com, que não seja apenas codigo bruto?

Comment: O que posso te dizer é que é muito simples criar essa aparência com CSS simples: crie a caixa de diálogo, coloque a regra "display: none" e depois use uma regra como ".pai:hover>.filho{display:block;}". A setinha pode ser feita com uma div rotacionada. Honestamente, bootstrap e afins, na minha opinião, só são úteis pela biblioteca de componentes, e esses você pode conseguir de outros lugares.

Comment: entendi bro e sobre esse tempo de duração de promoção é algo difícil de se conseguir? Eu já estou criando o carrinho de compras e tudo mais, mas não faço ideia de como fazer esse contador de tempo .

Comment: no momento está + ou - assim: http://prntscr.com/kxvfqs

Comment: E se vc poder me dar um exemplo dessa caixa de dialogo, algum tipo de tutorial ou algum exemplo ficaria grato .

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor você iniciar outra pergunta. Não vi nenhum contador, mas aqui tem um tutorial de como fazer um: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp (clique no ícone do mundo no canto superior direito para traduzir). Mas lembre que CSS é apenas para aparência. Desculpe, mas não tenho o código do menu pra te passar, mas o próprio site tem. Use as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e dê uma olhada como aquele foi feito.